# Optional checkbox in Scala Play - form does not validate

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I just started with Play and I'm trying to create a form with an "optional checkbox". The user must agree to the general terms (don't share your login credentials, ...). The second checkbox is optional and the user can decide whether this hint should be shown in the future again when he logs in the next time:
[image: UI]

I created some form validation code in my Scala controller:

```
case class AbuseStatus(abuseHintAccepted: Boolean, dismissAbuseHintInFuture: Boolean)
val abuseHintForm = Form(
    mapping(
        "abuseHintAccepted" -> checked("Please accept the general terms."),
        "dismissHintInFuture" -> boolean

    )(AbuseStatus.apply)(AbuseStatus.unapply) verifying ("you must accept the general terms", result => result match {
      case abuseStatus =>
      {
        abuseStatus.abuseHintAccepted.booleanValue()
      }
    })
  )
```

I'm using the following method to handle the POST request when the form has been sent.

```
def sendAbuseHintForm = Action {implicit request =>
    abuseHintForm.bindFromRequest.fold(
      formWithErrors =>
      {
        Logger.info("Form did not validate")
        formWithErrors.errors.map(error => Logger.info(error.messages.mkString(",")))
        Ok(views.html.abuseHint(formWithErrors))
      },
      abuseStatus =>
      {
        if(abuseStatus.dismissAbuseHintInFuture)
        {
          Logger.info(">>>dismissHintInFuture = true")
          Ok(views.html.home()).withCookies(showAbuseHintCookie)
        }
        else
          Ok(views.html.home())
      }
    )
  }
```

The form does not validate if both checkboxes are set to true. I would like it to validate when at least the first checkbox is set to true (the second is optional). How can I achieve this and what is the difference between

```
"abuseHintAccepted"->checked("...")
```

and

```
"dismissHintInFuture"->boolean
```

They both return a Mapping[Boolean].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried your example using Play 2.3.8 and it does appear to validate correctly when passing these parameters:

```
abuseHintAccepted:true
dismissHintInFuture:true
```

It would be worth making sure the form field names and values (true/false) that are posted are actually correct in all of the scenarios you describe (you haven't supplied that part of the code).

The difference between `boolean` and `checked(msg)` is that `checked(msg)` has validation applied ensuring the value is true - it is equivalent to `boolean verifying (msg, _ == true)` - (see [Play framework source](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.0.x/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/data/Forms.scala#L404)).

Finally, the `checked()` validation you have for `abuseHintAccepted` means that the `verifying` check on the whole form is not needed, but this shouldn't affect the behaviour of the form (it is just duplicate validation).

Comment: The field names in the HTML that are generated using a form helper were incorrect. Thanks for that hint!

Comment: I noticed that there are a lot of hard-coded strings in the code. If they don't match, it's hard to find out the problem. Is there a possibility to avoid this additional complexity (so that typos) cannot affect the functionality of the code?

Comment: @slashburn You could store the string fieldnames as vals on an object that you can reference from both the controller and view? I don't know of a better way.